# inserting an image into a word file, picture doesn not show

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm trying to write an introduction for a thesis, I tried inserting photos but it doesn't seem to be visible after inserting them, I will attach a picture so you can understand what I am talking about.

Ps: it worked on the first picture\chart, after that I just see the bottom corner.

[image]

Comment: It looks like your picture is behind the text. Try bringing it to the front.

Comment: i tried that, i can't select it when i write click on it to move it forward

Comment: What happens if you make the text frame bigger?

Comment: Your best option is to stop using frames. They are clearly confusing you.

Comment: i am not using any frames, i just drag the picture from desktop to the file and it appears like that, i tried to open it through insert, same result. what is confusing is the picture above it was inserted properly. i tried another pc,same result also.

Comment: Try inserting the picture with copy/paste instead of drag/drop. You have frames otherwise you would have all the resize handles.

Comment: it worked, thanks a lot for your time and effort! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: right-click on the picture and choose Wrap Text. Then choose various options until the picture is showing.

Also, instead of dragging the picture into the file, try using Insert > Picture.